# Styled ALT Text for not shown images

Tags: html-email

What happens if you use images in an email to replace text?

Most of the email clients do not load images by default. So... a normal user would not see anything.
But what happens when you use images this way:

```
<img src="notfound.jpg" alt="NOT FOUND"/>
```

Do they see the NOT FOUND alt if the image has not loaded? And what if it is styled similarly to the image to make it look a bit better, for example:

```
<img src="notfound.jpg" alt="NOT FOUND" style="font-size:24px;color:#FF00FF"/>
```

Are this alt texts styled accordingly?

Thanks

Comment: It's hard to test on so many browsers, email clients and mobile devices...

Comment: I just found someone that checked this, for anyone interested check http://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/entry/676/how-do-alt-attributes-appear-in-email/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A whole bunch of email clients don't actually render the alt tag - they either render the title tag, and the styles don't get applied to that, or they render the filename or something else.

So it works for a few clients, but it's nothing like widespread.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `title` tag in addition to your `alt` tag.

Unfortunately certain email client will ignore these tags and only show the link URL.